# Dual Boot Windows 10/Arch Linux grub not loading

Tags: windows-10, boot, grub, arch-linux, efi

I am having issues dual booting windows 10 and arch linux. Laptop boots straight into windows.

I tried reinstalling the grub but cannot override the windows boot manager. I tried fixing through windows using `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\arch\grubx64.efi` .I have a `/`, home and EFI boot partition in arch.

Model : Toshiba Satellite Pro L50-A531.

P.S I can access arch linux through windows by restarting in recovery mode and loading the `grub-rescue`.

Edit: I have disabled fast bootup and secure boot too

Output of `bcdedit /enum firmware`

```
Firmware Boot Manager
---------------------
identifier              {fwbootmgr}
displayorder            {bc7d6dd1-5c69-11e6-82cb-806e6f6e6963}
                        {bootmgr}
                        {01747bf1-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
                        {01747bf0-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
                        {01747bf2-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
timeout                 2

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\arch\grubx64.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {01747bf8-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01747bed-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
description             UEFI: Network Card

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01747bee-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
description             UEFI: Network Card

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01747bf0-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
description             EFI Network

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01747bf1-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
description             EFI USB Device

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {01747bf2-108f-11e6-82f7-fa7b5082fadb}
description             EFI DVD/CDROM

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {9d80f4af-1090-11e6-b8ee-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
description             UEFI: Hitachi HTS547564A9E384

Firmware Application (101fffff)
-------------------------------
identifier              {bc7d6dd1-5c69-11e6-82cb-806e6f6e6963}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\arch\grubx64.efi
description             arch
```

Comment: Disable the fast startup from windows settings

Comment: I have disabled fast startup and secure boot too

Comment: Try to insert `grubx64.efi` using a Windows Administrator command prompt.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Right clic on cmd.exe and choose run as administrator

Comment: I mean how do i insert grubx64.efi

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Windows_changes_boot_order

Comment: tried those steps again 
did not work :/

Comment: @viany Try this https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Using_the_rescue_console